# How to change Visual Studio's default MSTest, VSTest Parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, vstest

I want to be able to run tests from the Debugger in Visual Studio using MSTEST or VSTEST.  The current behavior is to delete Test Run Results (TRX files) when running locally.  The behavior I'm looking for is the equivalent of a build server running this command.

```
mstest /testcontainer:unittest.dll /resultsfile:results.trx
```

Because the Test Window already knows the dll, I'm guessing that we'd only need to pass in the /resultsfile switch.

Does anyone know of a way to configure Visual Studio so that the trx files are kept after the run?

I did not find anything within the TestSettings configurations that allows this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops;
May have just found the answeer:

```
<RunSettings> 
<MSTest>  
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
</MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```